# HTML Form in CakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, cakephp, formhelper

I don't want to use the FormHelper from CakePHP, because I want to use some Ajax in my app.
How can I pass the data from the form to the Controller? I'm using `$.post` from jQuery but I always get an error.
Thanks!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: in your controller you should be able to use $_POST, make sure your ajax/post request specifies the fields you want to use. one thing to be aware of is that if there are markup errors or anything mildly unusual in your manually created form, Cake will often destroy all the post data and you'll be left with a strange and confusing problem :) if that's the case, check out the manual on how to handle "blackholing": http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#handling-blackhole-callbacks

Comment: `I don't want to use the FormHelper from CakePHP, because I want to use some Ajax in my app` - what is FormHelper doing to your ajax call? I use FormHelper and Ajax all the time without any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Ajax with the CakePHP Form Helper.

**In your view file .ctp put:**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Model', array('id'=>'YourFormId', array('default'=>false)));
echo $this->Form->input('field');
echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
echo $this->Form-->end
```

Notice in your form->create your passing a default=>false which tells the form to not do a normal "Submit".

**At the bottom of your view file .ctp put:**

```
$data = $this->Js->get('#YourFormId')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true));
$this->Js->get('#YourFormId')->event(
  'submit',
   $this->Js->request(
      array('action' => 'yourAction', 'controller' => 'yourController'),
      array(
        'update' => '#flash',
        'data' => $data,
        'async' => true,    
        'dataExpression'=>true,
        'method' => 'POST'
        )
      )
     );
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

The above is CakePHP JS helper to help you write Ajax and Javascript which PHP. It basically grabs the form data that is being submitted and serializes it and passed it to /yourcontroller/youraction via ajax. The update=>#flash is telling Cake to Update the #flash div after the action is done.

**Remember in your Controller to have public**

```
public $helpers = array('Js');
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

Answer (score 0):

-- jQuery --

```
$.post('<?=$this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'xxx','action'=>'yyy'))?>', {a:1,b:2});
```

-- cakePHP --

```
    function yyy() {
       $a = $this->request->data['a'];
       $b = $this->request->data['b'];
    }
```